# Parse string on TASM

Tags: assembly, tasm

I need command interpereter for moving data beetween sources like mov.
Now, i get string

```
mov ah, 09h
mov dx, offset entstr
int 21h
```

How I can parse it to two variables?

for example:
string from console:

```
mov cs, 9
```

or

```
   mov cs, ax
```

to variables:
opr1: cs
opr2: 9

If input's string may contain zero or multiple spaces.

Comment: You can't `mov` to CS (the code-segment register), except maybe on some early silicon versions of 8086.  You can only set CS with a `jmp far`.  Oh, but that's the text you're parsing, not part of your program, so it doesn't matter whether it would assemble.

Comment: You'd do it in asm the same way you would in C; by looping a byte at a time and checking for space vs. non-space.  You can keep a count of what token number you're on, or if it's *always* going to be 2 operands then it might be easier to put the scanning code in a function and call it twice, i.e. fully unroll the parsing of a full line into a fixed sequence of function calls.  Looks like you need a loop to skip possible leading spaces before the first token.

Comment: there are no variables in assembly, so it's not clear, into what you want to parse it, what is `opr1` and `opr2`? Are these pointers into the original `entstr` memory buffer, or are there new buffers reserving some space, and the "cs" and "9" sub-strings are copied into them? Maybe related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39082250/4271923  (btw your code example is printing string with [`int 21h, ah=9` DOS service](http://stanislavs.org/helppc/int_21-9.html), not getting it)